# Updating data in a prev screen via navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

So I am working with passing data between screens in react-native by using a navigation stack. I have a home screen that checks a cache and if the cache is not empty it goes to screen A (with the cache value passed in) otherwise it goes to screen B. The user can also clear the cache at A for which they would be taken to B where they can re-add data to the cache. Once data has been re-added to the cache the user would be taken back to A with the new data passed in. The issue I'm having is that when I try to go back to A from B and pass in the new data the old cleared data passed in from the home screen shows instead of the new data from B. How can I get the new data in A from B using navigation? (checking the cache is only possible in the home page)

Flow summary: Home (old data) -> A (clears data) -> B, B (sends new data) -> A

`const ScreenA = ({ route, navigation }) => { // A's function header`

`const { result: data } = route.params; // getting the data in A`

`navigation.navigate("A", { newData}) // going from B to A with the new data;`

Comment: So far it looks perfectly fine. Please show some more code about how you use the new route param.

Comment: please note if you call it exactly like `navigation.navigate("A", { newData })` in screen B, you are not overwriting the `result` param, but passing a new param called `newData`.

Comment: You are correct I can get newData into screen A as a new variable. The only problem I'm having is that I am using use state( const [screenAVar, setscreenAVar] = useState(data) ) and when I try and make it conditional so that if the newData exists I set my use state to newData I get too many re-renders according to react-native.